# Which approach is better comparing a value in method check or checking if it exists in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, enums, time-complexity

Consider I have a scenario where certain awesome tasks need to be done when it satisfies the condition.

```
public class Check101 {

public static boolean validColor(String color) {
    return color.equals("RED")
            || color.equals("BLUE")
            || color.equals("GREEN");
}
public static List<String> validColorList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("RED","GREEN","BLUE"));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String color = "RED";
    if (validColor(color)) {
        //do awesome work
    }
    if(validColorList.contains(color)){
        //do awesome work
    }
}
```

}

*Right now it seems fine as it has only primary colors,
What if the valid color increases to let's say (i)100 and (ii)16 million color.
Then which is the best approach to go with?
Please note I was in a constraint not to use Set/HashMap or O(1) searchable containers and was asked to answer this weird scenario only.*

Comment: What's the reason for not using a Set?

Comment: my weird mentor asked me this question, only other approach he allowed me was a enum instead of list.

Comment: Neither approach is good for 16M colours.

Comment: I agree on the point for 16M colors but what for the point one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `List`, there is no reason to copy the list produced via `Arrays.asList("RED","GREEN","BLUE")` into another `ArrayList`. You can simply declare it like

```
public static List<String> validColorList = Arrays.asList("RED","GREEN","BLUE");
```

When you are not allowed to use a `Set`, both approaches perform a linear search, which is similarly bad performance-wise. But the list approach is simpler to maintain, as adding another value just requires, well, adding that value (to the initializer list), rather than adding another `if` statement.

That might scale well up to 100 values whereas even the performance drawback of a linear search might be irrelevant for 100 values, as long as you don’t perform the lookup very often, e.g. in a tight loop.

However, neither approach can be used for 16M colors. It’s not even impractical or having catastrophic performance, it’s just *impossible*. The maximum code size of a Java method is 65536 bytes, which applies to both, an ordinary method holding `if` statements or a class initializer constructing a `List`. Each expression or statement requires several bytes, so both approaches will stop working already at a threshold of a few thousand values. Even if you split the code into multiple methods, the number of string constants you can define within a single class are less than 65535.

To manage a larger number of values, you should embed the name list as a resource into your code and use something like, e.g.

```
public static final List<String> validColorList;
static {
    try {
        validColorList = Files.readAllLines(
            Paths.get(MyClass.class.getResource("color-list").toURI()));
    } catch(IOException|URISyntaxException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

But when we are at making such changes, there’s no reason to hesitate regarding the other strongly recommended change:

```
public static final Set<String> validColorList;
static {
    try {
        validColorList = new HashSet<>(Files.readAllLines(
            Paths.get(SO59045501.class.getResource("color-list").toURI())));
    } catch(IOException|URISyntaxException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

There is no equivalent for the approach of chaining `if` statements.

Comment: This is a very meaningful and descriptive answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you consider "better".

- When comparing to a value you have the advantage of direct access, while using the array you have the overhead of iterating the array. So there is a small performance advantage to value comparing approach.
- On the other end, using the array is a more generic approach that will be easily enhanced (reading the array from file or pulling it from the web). Moreover, it's more suitable for Dependency Injection (keeping the logic in the class while allowing the values for external source) which is more testable.

Comment: Thanks for answering, for primary 3 colors it hardly matters but when compared to around 100+ values (excluding the case for 16m), does the method value comparison have a performance advantage over the array loop? I also agree on the point for ease of maintenance of code.